# How do i set my Nikon D700 to bracketing starting at -1?

Tags: nikon, exposure, nikon-d7000, bracketing, fisheye

Totally new to Photography,

I am trying to take hemispherical photographs using a D700 And A Fisheye-Nikkor 8mm f/2.8 lens for my research. And i am required to set my camera as follow [*Exposure - Set up the camera so that it takes 3 photos at each point{Point being the same position} (2 f-stops below automatic exposure, 1 f-stop below automatic exposure and at automatic exposure). This can be achieved with bracketing starting at -1.*]

And I have no idea what, any of those words mean and what to do.

Any help please

Comment: Have you looked up *bracketing* in the index for the [*Nikon D700 User's Manual*](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D700_en.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

Set the camera to **A** (aperture priority) exposure mode. Set *Exposure Compensation* to -1. Set *Auto-Exposure Bracketing* to 3 shots with intervals of 1 stop. Set the *AEB order* to -, 0, +.

For how to set exposure compensation, AEB, and **A** exposure mode, please see the  [*Nikon D700 User's Manual*](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D700_en.pdf)